# Conditional Formatting - Table cells inconsistent with worksheet cells

Tags: excel

I'm trying to define some simple conditional formatting rules based on the value of different percentages. You can see that I have a table called attendance here:

[image: Overview of the problem]

And some cells below it. The cells below the table show the conditional formatting rules I'd like to apply to the table. In fact, the same conditional formatting rules are actually also applied to the column in the table. However, the results are inconsistent, and the table cells aren't displaying at the correct min, mid, and max colors I wanted.

You can see I confirm these settings here:

[image: Range of conditional formatting in table]

[image: Specific rule setup]

I also took a screenshot showing the complicated formula used to calculate the percentage. Does this have something to do with not making the conditional formatting work?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make sure that a cell with a value of 0% is colored in red, 50% in yellow and 100% in green, try this:[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help A.FC! I actually want 100% to be green, 90% to be yellow, and 80% or below to be red. I was able to get this working by using the decimal representation of the percent (number) rather than 'percent' in the settings. Thanks for your help, I have the solution now but I can't confirm your answer is correct because I'm new to the site and don't have enough reputation yet. Have a great day!